# Hibernate loss of precision in results when mapping a number (22,21) to BigDecimal

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, double, bigdecimal

I have this column in my Oracle 11g mapped as NUMBER (21,20), which is mapped in Hibernate as:

```
@Column(name = "PESO", precision = 21, scale = 20, nullable = false)
public BigDecimal getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

For a particular record for which the value of the column is  0.493 I get a BigDecimal whose value is 0.49299999999.
It seems that somewhere there is a loss of precision due (maybe) to a Double or Float conversion, but I couldn't track it down with a simple unit test like this:

```
Double d = new Double("0.493");
System.out.println((d));
```

Any variant of that code, using Float, BigDecimal and various constructors gives the same result: "0.493"...
Any hint on how should I map the column to avoid such issues?
I'm using Hibernate 3.5.6, with JPA annotations and Hibernate API (that is Session and not EntityManager)

Comment: it seems that this was not hibernate fault... This is entirely on SquirrelSql, which displays 0.493 for a value of 0.49299999999...
The value has always been that, both in the "source" file, both in database, as SqlDeveloper reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a result of initializing `BigDecimal` from `double`:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%21.20f", new BigDecimal(0.493)); 
// Prints 0,49299999999999999378
```

So, when `BigDecimal` initialized this way is saved in the database, it produces an inaccurate value, which is correctly loaded later.

If `BigDecimal` is initialized by string or if the value is set directly in Java everything works fine.

Comment: thanks for the example, probably the "%21.20" part does some trick because System.out.println(String.format("%f", new BigDecimal(0.493))); print almost fine -> "0,493000".
That was not my case though :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the winning solution has been the one based on [How do I map a BigDecimal in Hibernate so I get back the same scale I put in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544232/how-do-i-map-a-bigdecimal-in-hibernate-so-i-get-back-the-same-scale-i-put-in):

```
private final int SCALE = 2;
private final RoundingMode ROUNDING_MODE = RoundingMode.CEILING;

@Column(name = "value", precision = 8, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal value;

public BigDecimal getValue() {
    return value.setScale(SCALE, ROUNDING_MODE);
}
```

So, I just provided a getter that performed automatic tidying up of the big decimal.