# Hibernate - BigDecimal Mapping Precision

Tags: java, hibernate

**Problem:** 
Seems my mapping class for a big decimal is dropping 0 when grabbing values like 50.20 from the oracle database. It will grab the value correctly if its 50.23 but nothing with a 0 on the end. I imagine its something simple i am missing. Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Details**

Database: Oracle 11G
Field Definition: Numeric(8,2)

mapping getter/setter

```
    @Column ( name="PRICE", precision = 8, scale = 2 )
private BigDecimal price;

public BigDecimal getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
public void setPrice( BigDecimal price )
{
    this.price = price;
}
```

Comment: when I execute the hibernate .getList , it grab 50.2 and not 50.20 as it is in the database. The only thing I can think is its has to do with the mapping to the field. I also tried making it a double, made no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

50.2 is the same as 50.20, 50.200, etc. If you want to display it with two digits use [`java.text.DecimalFormat.format(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Specifying precision limits the maximum number of decimal digits, not the minimum.

Comment: Ya but why would hibernate trim it? In the database its 50.20, my mapping class shouldn't trim the trailing 0's I would think by default.

Comment: This is just e presentation issue. Noone trims the zero, it is just not displayed by toString.

Comment: You mean the toString even in the debugger? The price is mapped to a BigDecimal. In my code when I set the break point on the point where it gets that list of object values, i see the value mapped as 58.2 . No toString is called yet. I just thought by having that precision annotation on my @Column it would maintain the value.

Comment: As I said, precision is about the maximum. For setting how you want to display it use a decimal format.

Comment: The debugger uses toString to display BigDecimals.

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you that the creation of the `BigDecimal` value coming back from the database is done by the proprietary JDBC driver's implementation of the `getBigDecimal` method of the database-specific `ResultSet` sub-class.

I found this out by stepping thru the Hibernate source code with a debugger, while trying to find the answer to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568693/hibernate-bigdecimal-column-mapping-for-custom-dialect).

It seems that some implementations of the `getBigDecimal` method will either use the precision/scale defined in the database schema, or will try to optimise the `BigDecimal` returned by only defining the minimum precision/scale required to hold the value retrieved. I'm guessing that the Oracle driver is doing the latter.

See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544232/how-do-i-map-a-bigdecimal-in-hibernate-so-i-get-back-the-same-scale-i-put-in).

Answer (score -4):

In Business Logic class you can set value in this way also:

**object_name.setPrice(new BigDecimal(50.20));**