# Hibernate is mapping BigDecimal incorrectly

Tags: java, hibernate, scale, precision, bigdecimal

I have two `@Entity`s, both with a `BigDecimal` field as follows:

in one module:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price_range")
public class PriceRange extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @Column(name = "price", precision = 19, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal price;
```

and in another module:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_position")
public class InvoicePosition extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @Column(name = "optimized_cost", precision = 19, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal optimizedCost;
```

both create tables in my database with the correct precision and scale values:

```
Table invoice_position
======================
id,optimized_cost, ...
----------------------
optimized_cost   decimal(19,4)
```

and

```
Table price_range
=================
id, price, ...
-----------------
price            decimal(19,4)
```

A Test Frontend saves the values correctly to the database.

However in a unit test, one of the two returns a value with a rounding error:

```
0.520000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

*(debugger says: sacle = 51 and precision = 0)*

while the other is working fine:

```
0.5200
```

*(debugger says: scale = 4, precision = 4)*

Both values are retrieved from the database in the same way *(with an EntityManager building a CriteriaQuery with a CriteriaBuilder inside a JpaRepository)*:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = invoiceProvider.findAll();
List<PriceRange> priceRanges = priceRangeProvider.findAll();
```

What could be the problem here? Or better: Where could it go wrong, if the Entity has the correct scale and precision and the database as well?

I'm quite at a loss here, where can I look for the error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734036/hibernate-loss-of-precision-in-results-when-mapping-a-number-22-21-to-bigdecim

Comment: Looks like that could be it. What's the best practice then for initializing `BigDecimal` in a unit test? Using `String` feels... weird..

Comment: You can also initialize them with `long` and scale, but it doesn't look good too.

Comment: Still, using a String is the correct way to go. Anything else will fail because of rounding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, marking this as answered as per comments with the solution being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544232/how-do-i-map-a-bigdecimal-in-hibernate-so-i-get-back-the-same-scale-i-put-in)