# Precision Java Float in MySQL with JPA (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, floating-point

I have a precision problem storing a float value in mysql via jpa (EclipseLink). In my code I have annotated the field with

```
@Column(precision=15, scale=7)
private float x;
```

But when i store a value like 322,249878 the database returns 322.25. Whats going on there :)?

Comment: What is the definition for the column in the db? And if JPA creates the tables, could you get a hold of the DDL?

Comment: @esej: the definition for the column is float. The DDL for that colum is X FLOAT as well.

Comment: Side note: a float cannot contain 15 decimal digits. It is too small.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`precision` and `scale` settings are only applicable to exact numeric types (i.e. `BigDecimal` in Java and `decimal` in MySQL).

Floating point types (`float` and `double`) are approximate by their nature, therefore these settings don't make sense for them.

Also note that if you change type of this field to `BigDecimal` [you should initialize it with precise values as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734036/hibernate-loss-of-precision-in-results-when-mapping-a-number-22-21-to-bigdecim/5734172#5734172).

Comment: Ok thanks for that hint but it doesn't change anything for the precision ;-)

Comment: @jstr: Recheck it. Java type should be `BigDecimal`, MySQL type should be `decimal(15, 7)` (Hibernate will generate it from this annotation if you use schema generation), and field should be initialized by precise value.

Comment: @jstr: Oh, it's EclipseLink, perhaps it behaves differently somehow.

Comment: Ok so now I use BigDecimal which I initialize with Float.toString(x)) and with mit annotation @Column(precision=15, scale=7) the precision is preserved... works for me